# Convert mysql DB timestamp to int time for PHP touch

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql timestamp which looks like this: `2016-08-31 21:54:33` . I need to use this timestamp in [PHP touch](http://php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php): `bool touch ( string $filename [, int $time = time() [, int $atime ]] )`

How can I best convert into the `int` value needed in `touch`?

Comment: `touch($file, strtotime($row['time']));` - like this?

Comment: or convert the time on select `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(your_time_field) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an object oriented syle:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime("2016-08-31 21:54:33");
echo $dateTime->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert string to timestamp you can use one of:

```
$str = '2016-08-31 21:54:33';
// Option #1:
strtotime($str);

// Option #2:
strptime($str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
```